# No such host is known, ClientDependency

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm hosting my project in a test server (proyectos.legendsoft.com.ve), but since i need this project to access some cookies from another host, i had to change my host file on my local machine:

```
 75.125.228.200     legendsoft.batanga.com
```

Now this seems to cause problems with the ClientDependendy library, even if it works fine on my localhost:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost.batanga.com
```

Anyone know any way to fix this or i just have to remove this library?

This is the complete error:

```
Server Error in '/Batanga' Application.
No such host is known

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


 [SocketException (0x2af9): No such host is known]
   System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name) +250
   System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6) +144
   System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress) +435
   ClientDependency.Core.UriExtensions.IsLocalUri(Uri uri) +76
   ClientDependency.Core.Module.<>c__DisplayClass2.<ReplaceContent>b__1(Match m) +264
   System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexReplacement.Replace(MatchEvaluator evaluator, Regex regex, String input, Int32 count, Int32 startat) +244
   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(String input, MatchEvaluator evaluator) +84
   ClientDependency.Core.Module.RogueFileFilter.ReplaceContent(String html, String namedGroup, String[] extensions, ClientDependencyType type, String regex) +143
   ClientDependency.Core.Module.RogueFileFilter.ReplaceScripts(String html) +260
   ClientDependency.Core.Module.RogueFileFilter.UpdateOutputHtml(String html) +16
   System.Func`2.Invoke(T arg) +0
   ClientDependency.Core.Module.ResponseFilterStream.OnTransformCompleteStringInternal(MemoryStream ms) +107
   ClientDependency.Core.Module.ResponseFilterStream.Flush() +109
   System.Web.HttpWriter.FilterIntegrated(Boolean finalFiltering, IIS7WorkerRequest wr) +610
   System.Web.HttpResponse.FilterOutput() +100
   System.Web.CallFilterExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +77
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +171
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something ClientDependency needs to fix. You can simply turn off rogue file filtering to work around this issue though, everything else will work fine.

I've created an issue for this, http://clientdependency.codeplex.com/workitem/13173

Answer (score 2):

The error the stack trace is reporting is actually from `System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)` and not from your ClientDependency library. Make sure the server you're running the application on can resolve the hostname you're passing it (try to ping the address from that machine and see if it works).